# Type 'object' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator

Tags: angular, typescript

`data.technologies` is an array and I would like to get the output of that array.

This is how the output of `data.technologies` looks like:

[image]

```js
this.profileService.getEntities().subscribe(data => {
  for (const technology of data.technologies) {
    console.log(technology);
  }
});
```

The type of `getEntities()` is `Observable<IprofileData>`.

```js
export interface IprofileData {  
  technologies: object;
}
```

TypeScript gives me the error:

> TS2488: Type 'object' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if `data` is an array, `data.technologies` should normally be undefined and that's nothing you can iterate over. How does a value in your array look like? (string, object, …). What is the expected value in your input?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen sorry, my bad ... `data.technologies` returns an array, not `data`.

Comment: @Reaza and where is type definition of data?

Comment: @MaciejSikora the type of `data` is an interface that looks like this: `technologies: object;`

Comment: Could you `console.log(data.technologies)` and give us the output please ?

Comment: So you have an issue with type definition. Can you paste it?

Comment: @MaciejSikora you are right. It must be because I am using `object` but how can I turn it to an array, since "array" is not a type? I have updated my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Runtime structure is correct, it is an array, but the type says (from your comment) that it is just an object. Object has no iterator protocol, array has.

Example type which should fulfill the need:

```
type Data {
  ...// some other props
  technologies: string[] // change string into any type you have there
}
```

Answer (score 32):

For future googlers:

This is also the error message returned if you forget to objectify your function inputs.

Example:

```
setCurrRowData(...currRowData, sort_order: num);
```

Fix:

```
setCurrRowData( { ...currRowData, sort_order: num } );
//              ^                                 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `data.technologies` a function (you mentioned it "returned" an array)? If so, you simply need to call it like this:

```js
this.profileService.getEntities().subscribe(data => {
    for (const technology of data.technologies()) {
        console.log(technology);
    }
});
```

Comment: No, `data.technologies` is not a function. What I mean is the output of it is an array.

Comment: So `data.technologies` in an array? Your wording is confusing, that's all.

Comment: I have added an image of the output of `data.technologies`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, when I was trying to destructure an object as an array
i.e
I was trying

```
const [mutation] = useMutation()
```

what was needed is

```
const {mutation} = useMutation()
```